# Re-running JQuery's selectors and actions after a programmatic insertion of new content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fellow JQuery hackers, hello :-)

Suppose you have the following code:

```
$('.links').click(function(){
    //Do something
}
```

And I then insert dynamic content into a DIV's HTML content (Say, for example, after clicking a button, the new content gets inserted). This content has the "links" class. The problem is that the "click" button doesn't get registered with the newly inserted content.

**How do I tell JQuery to re-select all the elements with a "links" class and apply the above function on them? Can this be automated?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to use event delegation:

```
$('.links').live("click",function(){
    //Do something
});
```

That will prevent dynamically inserted elements with the class `links` from losing their click event handler. Note that you will also need **jQuery 1.3 or later** for that to work.
See [Events/live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

Another way is to re-bind using the callback of whichever of jQuery's [ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) methods you have opted to use, example:

```
$('#someDiv').load('page.html', function() {
    $('.links').click(function(){
        //Do something
    });
});
```

or neater still:

```
function initLinks() {
    $('.links').click(function(){
        //Do something
    }
}

$('#someDiv').load('page.html',initLinks);
```

Comment: WARNING: there is an error with using live with FF. If you do right clicking something that is ".live"ed will be counted as being left clicked.

Comment: Apart from that, use the above (I've even voted it up myself, I just wanted to throw that extra info in for you)

Comment: Wow, good catch on that bug! A workaround for that would be to filter for left mouse button clicks:

    function(e) {
        if (e.button == 0) { // 0 = left, 1 = middle, 2 = right
        }
    }